# Memory leak in JSZip

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, jszip

I am using JSZip in my little React application. I need to fetch attachments from sharepoint list. Attachments size about 3 gb so I made a decision to download it in parts (200mb). But I got big RAM consumption (more than 3500 mb). I can't find memory leak

Source code. This function outside of React component:

```
var JSZip = require("jszip");
async function testUploadAllAttachments() {    
    const ceilSizebytes = 209715200;
    // actually it count blobs sizes
    let blobCounter = 0;    
    
    const filterItemsDate = await sp.web.lists.getByTitle("Reports").items.getAll();
    console.log("filterItemsDate: ", filterItemsDate);

    let zip = new JSZip();

    for (const item of filterItemsDate) {        
        let allItemAttachments = await sp.web.lists.getByTitle("Reports").items.getById(item.Id).attachmentFiles();

        let itemFolder = zip.folder(item.Id);
        console.log("itemFolder: ", itemFolder);
        console.log("blobCounter: ", blobCounter);
        
        for (const attach of allItemAttachments) {
            let urlToFetch = attach.ServerRelativePath.DecodedUrl;

            let blob = await fetch(urlToFetch).then(response => {
                return response.blob();
            });
            // Blob size control
            blobCounter += blob.size;
            if (blobCounter > ceilSizebytes) {

                blobCounter = 0;
                zip.remove(item.Id);                    

                await zip.generateAsync({ type: "blob", 
                compression: "DEFLATE", 
                compressionOptions:{
                    level: 6
                } })
                    .then(function (content) {
                        // saveAs(content, "examplePart.zip");
                        // content = null;
                    })
                zip = null;
                zip = new JSZip();
                
                // Recreate missing item on removing step
                let itemFolderReset = zip.folder(item.Id);
                for (let i = 0; i < allItemAttachments.length; i++) {
                    let urlToFetchReset = allItemAttachments[i].ServerRelativePath.DecodedUrl;
                                        
                    let blobReset = await fetch(urlToFetch).then(response => {
                        return response.blob();
                    });

                    itemFolderReset.file(allItemAttachments[i].FileName, blobReset );
                    blobCounter += blobReset.size;
                }
                continue;
            }
            else {
                itemFolder.file(attach.FileName, blob);
                
            }

        }

    }
    await zip.generateAsync({ type: "blob" })
        .then(function (content) {
            saveAs(content, "example.zip");
        })    
    
}
```

Comment: I don't see in your code where you're breaking it into 200 MB parts.  But didn't you just say the attachments are 3GB in size?  Why would you expect memory consumption to be less than that?

Comment: @RobertHarvey It breaks into 200mb parts after this "if (blobCounter > ceilSizebytes) ... await zip.generateAsync(" . Ye, I comment out "saveAs". But I expect that when I make "zip = new JSZip();" blobs will delete.